# groupby on a pandas data frame with a customized aggregation function

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by

Suppose we have the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal' : ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed' : [380.1, 370.3, 24.77, -12.55]})
```

I have to construct a function similar to the minimum in absolute value, it must return the element closer to zero. By grouping by 'Animal', in our case, it should return:

```
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon     370.30
1  Parrot     -12.55
```

I tried a function like this:

```
def nearzero():
   absolute = [abs(number) for number in data]
   i = absolute.index(min(absolute))
   return data[i]
```

It should return the element found in the index where the absolute value is minimum. But it does not work:

```
df.groupby(['Animal']).agg({'Max Speed': [nearzero]})
```

Is the function or groupby badly defined?

Comment: `df.groupby('Animal').min().reset_index()` ??

Comment: Can you add more data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: No min(2,-10) is -10 but 2 is closer to zero.

Comment: my output must keep the sign, so it must report the negatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function as:

```
def nearzero(data):
    dat = data.tolist()
    absolute = [abs(number) for number in dat]
    return dat[absolute.index(min(absolute))]
```

Note that this function is called with a **df column** (*Series*) as the
argument, but selection must be performed from the underlying **list**.

Then call:

```
df.groupby(['Animal'])['Max Speed'].apply(nearzero)
```

**The second alternative**, without explicit conversion to the underlying list:

Define the function as:

```
def nearzero2(data):
    return data[data.abs().idxmin()]
```

Then call:

```
df.groupby(['Animal'])['Max Speed'].apply(nearzero2)
```

Or to get the result just as in your questrion:

```
df.groupby(['Animal']).agg({'Max Speed': nearzero2}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indices by mins per groups, also convert column `Max Speed` to [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html), last call `loc` for select rows:

```
df = df.loc[df['Max Speed'].abs().groupby(df['Animal']).idxmin()]
print (df)
   Animal  Max Speed
1  Falcon     370.30
3  Parrot     -12.55
```

Another solution with new column:

```
df['Max Speed Abs'] = df['Max Speed'].abs()
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Animal')['Max Speed Abs'].idxmin()]
```

EDIT: For `groupby` by multiple `Series` use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal' : ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed' : [380.1, 370.3, 24.77, -12.55],
                   'Dates':['2010-10-09'] * 4})  

df = df.loc[df['Max Speed'].abs().groupby([df['Animal'], df['Dates']]).idxmin()]
print (df)
   Animal  Max Speed       Dates
1  Falcon     370.30  2010-10-09
3  Parrot     -12.55  2010-10-09
```

Comment: thanks for the really smart solution. I simplified the data frame and in my real case it has three columns. Animal, Dates (format date) and 'Max Speed'. I have to group for Animal and Dates .. I tried df.loc [df ['Max Speed']. Abs () .groupby (df [['Animal', 'Dates']]). Idxmin ()] but it does not work .

Comment: @stefanodv - Can you check `df.loc[df['Max Speed'].abs().groupby([df['Animal'], df['Dates']]).idxmin()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function in python,

```
def abs_min(x):
    for elem in x:
        if abs(elem) == min(abs(x)):
            return elem

df.groupby('Animal')['Max Speed'].apply(abs_min)

Animal
Falcon    370.30
Parrot    -12.55
```

Or use generator,

```
df.groupby('Animal')['Max Speed'].apply(lambda x: next(i for i in x if abs(i) == min(abs(x))))
```